# php mailer how to preserver text formatting

Tags: php

The below code preserve the message formatting when sending to GMAIL, YAHOO, HOTMAIL but the opposite when access through Outlook or Mozilla Thunderbird showing an empty message.

I tried N2blr but it giving the right result.

Any idea?

```
$fp = fopen($attachment_temp, "rb");
$file = fread($fp, $attachment_size);

$file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
$num = md5(time());

//Normal headers

$headers  = "From: ".$namefrom."<".$mailhost.">\r\n";
$headers .="Reply-To: ".$emailfrom."\r\n";
$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

// This two steps to help avoid spam

$headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()."   TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

// With message

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= "".$message."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n";

// Attachment headers


$headers  .= "Content-Type:".$attachment_type." ";
$headers  .= "name=\"".$attachment_name."\"r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
$headers  .= "filename=\"".$attachment_name."\"\r\n\n";
$headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--".$num."--";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there's a error here:

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
  $headers .= "".$message."\n";
  $headers .= "--".$num."\n";

The third line ought to read

$headers .= "\r\n".$message."\n";

even if some servers are able to recover from this kind of errors. Also, you might want to move from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 for a more complete internationalization support.

Comment: Yes after seeing your comment and RDs it seems the ISOs has giving the issue. It works perfectly with this:


$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"; 
$headers .= "".nl2br($message)."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n";

Comment: That ought to work. The missing `\r\n` would have prevented some readers from realizing the headers were finished and the message had started, thereby making them not display a part (or all) of the message body. `$headers` is a bit of a misnomer, really.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your time.